# Is it possible to add an installer, run it and delete it during one build step in Docker?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to create a Docker image from a pretty large installer binary (300+ MB). I want to add the installer to the image, install it, and delete the installer. This doesn't seem to be possible:

```
COPY huge-installer.bin /tmp
RUN /tmp/huge-installer.bin
RUN rm /tmp/huge-installer.bin   # <- has no effect on the image size
```

Using multiple build stages doesn't seem to solve this, since I need to run the installer in the final image. If I could execute the installer directly from a previous build stage, without copying it, that would solve my problem, but as far as I know that's not possible.

Is there any way to avoid including the full weight of the installer in the final image?

Comment: Have you found time yet to try one of the provided solutions?

Comment: @bellackn Yeah thanks for reminding me. None of the solutions were applicable for me. I found an alternative solution by using a HTTP server to host my project directory. I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by using the built-in HTTP server in Python to make the project directory available to the image over HTTP.

Inside the Dockerfile, I can run commands like this, piping scripts directly to bash using curl:

```
RUN curl "http://127.0.0.1:${SERVER_PORT}/installer-${INSTALLER_VERSION}.bin" | bash
```

Or save binaries, run them and delete them in one step:

```
RUN curl -O "http://127.0.0.1:${SERVER_PORT}/binary-${INSTALLER_VERSION}.bin" && \
    ./binary-${INSTALLER_VERSION}.bin && \
    rm binary-${INSTALLER_VERSION}.bin
```

I use a Makefile to start the server and stop it after the build, but you can use a build script instead.

Here's a Makefile example:

```
SHELL := bash
IMAGE_NAME := app-test
VERSION := 1.0.0
SERVER_PORT := 8580

.ONESHELL:

.PHONY: build
build:
    # Kills the HTTP server when the build is done
    function cleanup {
        pkill -f "python3 -m http.server.*${SERVER_PORT}"
    }
    trap cleanup EXIT

    # Starts a HTTP server that makes the contents of the project directory 
    # available to the image
    python3 -m http.server -b 127.0.0.1 ${SERVER_PORT} &>/dev/null &
    sleep 1

    EXTRA_ARGS=""

    # Allows skipping the build cache by setting NO_CACHE=1
    if [[ -n $$NO_CACHE ]]; then
        EXTRA_ARGS="--no-cache"
    fi

    docker build $$EXTRA_ARGS \
        --network host \
        --build-arg SERVER_PORT=${SERVER_PORT} \
        -t ${IMAGE_NAME}:latest \
        .

    docker tag ${IMAGE_NAME}:latest ${IMAGE_NAME}:${VERSION}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to download the bin from a website then run it:

```
RUN wget http://myweb/huge-installer.bin && /tmp/huge-installer.bin && rm /tmp/huge-installer.bin
```

in this way your image layer will not contain the binary you download

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it thoroughly, but wouldn't such an approach be viable? (Besides LinPy's answer, which is way easier if you have the possibility to just do it that way.)

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest

COPY entrypoint.sh /tmp/entrypoint.sh
RUN \
  echo "I am an image that can run your huge installer binary!" \
  && echo "I will only function when you give it to me as a volume mount."

ENTRYPOINT [ "/tmp/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

/tmp/your-installer # install your stuff here

while true; do
  echo "installer finished, commit me now!"
  sleep 5
done
```

Then run:

```
$ docker build -t foo-1
$ docker run --rm --name foo-1 --rm -d -v $(pwd)/your-installer:/tmp/your-installer
$ docker logs -f foo-1
# once it echoes "commit me now!", run the next command
$ docker commit foo-1 foo-2
$ docker stop foo-1
```

Since the installer was only mounted as a volume, the image `foo-2` should not contain it anymore. You could also go and build another Dockerfile based on `foo-2` to change the entrypoint, for example.

Cf. [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/)